# Design Pattern for RateLimited API calls

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a service class, which needs to call different apis from other service.
But each API have some limits, So I am using Guava's Ratelimiter to enforce the limit of the operation

```
@Singleton

public class A {

    private final RateLimiter apiCallX;
    private final int timeoutInSecondsForAPIX;

    private final RateLimiter apiCallY;
    private final int timeoutInSecondsForAPIY;

    @Inject
    public A ( @Named("apiCallXRateLimiter") apiCallX,
    @Named("apiCallXRateLimiter") apiCallY,
    @Named("apiCallXRateLimiter") apiCallZ,
    ){
      this.apiCallX = apiCallX;
      ...
    }

    public ResponseX callAPIX (){
      ...
    }

    public ResponseY callAPIY (){
      ...
    }

    private modelTransformer(){ //each for request and response and for each call.
     ...
    }

}
```

I am thinking to use inheritance to avoid clustering all the operation calls from this class.
What are the other design patterns I could use in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an AOP framework or the patterns behind it, like proxy pattern:

```
interface ServiceX {
    ResponseX execute();
}

@Alternative
@Named("serviceX")
class ServiceXImpl implements ServiceX {

    @Override
    public ResponseX execute() {
        //call to X API
        return null;
    }
}

@Default
class ServiceXProxyImpl implements ServiceX {
    @Inject
    @Named("serviceXLimiter")
    RateLimiter rateLimiter;
    @Inject
    @Named("serviceX")
    ServiceX serviceX;

    @Override
    public ResponseX execute() {
        rateLimiter.acquire();
        return serviceX.execute();
    }
}
```

Now wherever you declare `@Inject ServiceX serviceX` your DI framework should inject the implementation with rate limiter